# Structure and list in C

Tags: c, list

If I have a structure, for exemple that allow to handle books of a library, how do I implement a list in this code?

I wrote this code, that actually do most of the things I need, but I need to do it with lists. I also need to read and save a file. I know how to do it, but not exactly where to put the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#define max 100
#define LEN 1000

/* STRUTTURA DATI */
typedef struct
{
char author[max];
char title[max];
char edit[max];
int year;
} Book;

typedef struct
{
Book elements[LEN];
int num_books;
} List;


 /* PROTOTIPI DI FUNZIONE */
 int menu();
 List add_book();
 void print_list(List l);
 void old_book(List l);
 int search_author(List l, char author[]);

int main()
{
int choice;
List LL;
char author[max];
int ishethere;

while(choice=menu())
{
    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1:
        system("CLS");
        printf("Hey, hey, YOU! LISTEN! Add a book! :3\n");
        LL=add_book();
        printf("\n");
        print_list(LL);
        system("PAUSE");
        break;
    case 2:
        system("CLS");
        printf("So... Wanna know what's the oldest book?");
        old_book(LL);
        printf("\n");
        system("PAUSE");
        break;
    case 3:
        system("CLS");
        printf("Do you want to search an author? Come on lets go and play!");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(author);
        ishethere=search_author(LL, author);
        if(ishethere!=-1)
            printf("He is in the list\n\n");
        else
            printf("I don't know him. Sorry.");
        system("PAUSE");
        break;
    case 4:
        system("CLS");
        print_list(LL);
        system("PAUSE");
        break;
    case 0:
        return(0);
    }
    }
 }

 /* DEFINIZIONI DI FUNZIONI */
 int menu()
{
int choice;
printf("* * * Books' Menu * * *\n");
printf("* [1] Add Books       *\n");
printf("* [2] Search Old Book *\n");
printf("* [3] Search Author   *\n");
printf("* [4] Print Books     *\n");
printf("* [0] Bye bye!        *\n");
printf("* * * * * * * * * * * *\n");
printf("What do you want to do?  ");
scanf("%d", &choice);
while(choice<0 || choice>4)
{
    printf("DAMMIT! From 0 to 4, can you read?\n");
    printf("What do you want to do?  ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    return choice;
}
return choice;
system("PAUSE");
}

List add_book()
{
List l;
int i;
printf("How many books do you want to add? ");
scanf("%d", &l.num_books);
fflush(stdin);
for(i=0; i<l.num_books; i++)
{
    printf("Type author: ");
    gets(l.elements[i].author);
    printf("Type title: ");
    gets(l.elements[i].title);
    printf("Type editor: ");
    gets(l.elements[i].edit);
    printf("Type year: ");
    scanf("%d", &l.elements[i].year);
    fflush(stdin);
}

return l;
}

 void print_list(List l)
{
int i;
for (i=0; i<l.num_books; i++)
{
    printf("Book n.%d\n", i+1);
    printf("Author: %s\n", l.elements[i].author);
    printf("Title: %s\n", l.elements[i].title);
    printf("Editor: %s\n", l.elements[i].edit);
    printf("Year: %d\n\n", l.elements[i].year);
}
}

 void old_book(List l)
{
int i;
Book old=l.elements[0];
int index_old=0;
for (i=0; i<l.num_books; i++)
{
    if(old.year>l.elements[i].year)
    {
        old=l.elements[i];
        index_old=i;
    }
}
printf("The oldest book is: \n");
printf("'%s', by %s, published in %d from %s.\n\n", old.title, old.author, old.year, old.edit);
}

int search_author(List l, char author[])
 {
 int i, isitthere=-1;
for (i=0; i<l.num_books; i++)
    if(strcmp(l.elements[i].author, author)==0)
  {
    isitthere=1;
 }
return isitthere;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a node of elements you want to be in your list but not like you did. I can give you an example:

```
typedef struct node List;
struct node
{
Book elements[LEN];
int num_books;
List * next;
};
```

When you say just typedef struct {...} you cant put a pointer inside of brackets because you cant say what type of node do you want to point. **When you create a list, you must have a pointer that points to a next element** so this above is correct way. If you want like you did, i suggest you to give a name to struct for example

```
typedef struct node{
Book elements[LEN];
int num_books;
struct node * next;
} List;
```

This should work too.

Comment: I see. And is it the only modify it needs?

Comment: Now you have node for the list. You create a head pointer and just create a list like every other list. Just to point it out when you are trying to access the elements of the `Book`, take care of `->` and `.` cause for example if you want to access the author, you should access like this `head -> elements[i].author`

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to put in the list form you wrote above even the first typedef?

Comment: You have a choice. If you want to stick with your idea, you should pick the second one. Just notice if you don't put the name of the struct when you are creating a list, you cant make a pointer to the list because you cant specify the type of node you want to point. That is all, everything else stays the same 
But if you pick the second one, you have to typedef first because compiler reads your code from top to down and if you don't do it, it would probably be a syntax error

Comment: Okay, I think I got it and it compiled without errors. Thank you so much. I'm sorry to bother you, but could you please help with the print part? The one I knew print on file as binary data...

Comment: No problem :) I think i don't understand your question. If you want to print into a txt file, you should open it on the mode "wt" or "w". But if you are using the binary file, you just can't read it like txt file. The text file is type of binary file where all sequences of bits are set to characters so you can read it. The binary file itself has the sequences of bits that are organized on format you put there. Txt file has 8 bits for character because of ascii and binary vary from the type you put there like int is 4 bytes, double is 8 and so on.

Comment: What do you suggest to print it into a file?

Comment: I don't know it is up to you and the problem you have. If want a report or just to list things out i suggest using a txt file. If you want just permanent storage and you know how you organized bits there, then use binary file. That is all i can say